# partial view validation with nav tabs having issues - mvc 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, validation, nav

I have a partial view with a `nav` bar on it.  Let's say there are two tabs in it and both tabs have same property. My requirement is it should only validate one `textbox` element.

It's server side validation. And all the script tags like `unobtrusive,validate` are in place.

My Partial View:

```
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#id1" data-toggle="tab">First</a></li>
        <li><a href="#id2" data-toggle="tab">Second</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab-content 1">

    @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.FirstName)
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.FirstName) // lets say this is the element for tab 1


  </div>

  <div class="tab-content 1">
       @using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post))
       {
           @Html.LabelFor(m=> m.FirstName)
           @Html.TextBoxFor(m=> m.FirstName) 
           @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=> n.FirstName) // it should only validate this element.
       }
  </div>
```

When I am on tab 1, it still tries to validate tab 2 field since both share the same `property`.

How do I prevent this effectively?

Comment: If you examine the HTML are the models' form ids identical?

Comment: yes they are.........

Comment: Ids need to be unique. When you are on Tab-N the other tab is still on the page.

Comment: yep they are...cuz they both are on the same partial view and its bootstrap nav-tabs

Answer (score 0):

use begin form for tab1

```
$("#tab1").validate({   });
```

and for tab2 is

```
$("#tab2").validate({   });
```

Comment: @StevenWestbrook, please shed some light on my issue